# JavascriptCore hangs when running a JS with callback

Tags: objective-c, xcode, javascriptcore

I am trying to run a JS function using JavascriptCore from Objective-C. Here's the JS code:

```
var FeedParser = require('feedparser');
var run = function(data, options){
  var feedparser = new FeedParser(options);
  feedparser.on('readable', function() {
    if(callback){
      callback(this.read());
    }
  });
  feedparser.end(data);
};

module.exports = {
  run: run
};
```

And here's the Objective-C code that invokes the JS:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rss" ofType:@"js"];
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *js = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                         usedEncoding:&encoding
                                                error:&error];

JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
[context setExceptionHandler:^(JSContext *context, JSValue *value) {
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
}];
context[@"callback"] = ^(JSValue *val){
    @try{
        if([val isString]){
            NSLog(@"%@", [val toString]);
        } else if([val toDictionary][@"0"]){
            NSLog(@"%@", [val toArray]);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", [val toDictionary]);
        }
    }
    @catch(NSException *e){
    }
};
[context evaluateScript:js];

JSValue *parse = context[@"rss"][@"run"];
[parse callWithArguments:@[data, o]];
```

Note:

1. Just to be clear, this approach works fine for all other JS functions that immediately return results. I am using browserify to package them all into a single JS. I'm just noticing problems with functions that return asynchronously via callback. (Notice I'm adding `callback` function to the context.
2. When I run this on XCode it hangs (not just the app but also the XCode editor itself, and it never recovers until I kill the process from Activity Monitor).
3. However for some reason it returns the result as soon as I unplug the iPhone from my laptop. (At this point XCode is still in a limbo state until I kill it)
4. Once detached from XCode, the app runs fine. It just hangs while it's running from XCode invoked run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are trying to convert some JavaScript value to NSDictionary via toDictionary call. This method attempts to convert value recursively, so it leads to a hung often. I suspect that any JS value with circular references causes infinite recursion in this case. Try to work with JSValue directly instead.